# Error in Setting up selenium in Node environment

Tags: node.js, windows, selenium

I am following a tutorial on how to set up selenium in a node environment:
https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-setup-selenium-on-node-environment-ee33023da72d

After following some steps I get an error while testing. These are the steps that I followed:
So first i initialize npm environment on windows:
mkdir node_testing
cd node_testing
npm init -y
npm install selenium-webdriver

then I installed chromedriver (105.0.5195.52) for chrome version 105.0.5195.102 (not the exact same version because there isn't one). I also added the chromedrivers path to system paths.

After that im asked to run the following code as a test  but it results in an error:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
driver.get('http://www.google.com').then(function(){
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver\n').then(function(){
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
      console.log(title)
      if(title === 'webdriver - Google Search') {
         console.log('Test passed');
      } else {
         console.log('Test failed');
      }
     driver.quit();
    });
  });
});
```

**Result:**
Google Chrome opens and the following prints in the terminal:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56409/devtools/browser/9b9b2e99-4bb1-4d8d-8939-c68b39c045b9
C:\Users\ibo\node_testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:522
    let err = new ctor(data.message)
              ^

ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\Users\ibo\node_testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:522:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\ibo\node_testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:589:13)
    at Executor.execute (C:\Users\ibo\node_testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:514:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async thenableWebDriverProxy.execute (C:\Users\ibo\node_testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:740:17) {  
  remoteStacktrace: 'Backtrace:\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x011CDF13+2219795]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x01162841+1779777]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x01074100+803072]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x0109E523+976163]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x0109DB93+973715]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x010BE7FC+1107964]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x010994B4+955572]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x010BEA14+1108500]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x010CF192+1175954]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x010BE616+1107478]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x01097F89+950153]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x01098F56+954198]\n' +
    '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x014C2CB2+3040210]\n' +
    '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x014B2BB4+2974420]\n' +
    '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x01266A0A+565546]\n' +
    '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x01265680+560544]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x01169A5C+1808988]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x0116E3A8+1827752]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x0116E495+1827989]\n' +
    '\tOrdinal0 [0x011780A4+1867940]\n' +
    '\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x772BFA29+25]\n' +
    '\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x774D7A9E+286]\n' +
    '\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x774D7A6E+238]\n'
}
PS C:\Users\ibo\node_testing> [11296:19112:0911/155158.526:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:51:58.526] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[11296:19112:0911/155158.531:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:51:58.530] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read 
descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

Any suggestions are welcome Ive been stuck on this for days.

Comment: That article is 2.5 years old and even then node + selenium was on it's last legs. Choose Puppeteer / Playwright or switch to Python.

Answer (score 0):

allow me to answer. Maybe you missed the instructions from the tutorial.

**"The next thing to do is to download the right web driver for the browser you will be testing on"**

So all you have to do is match the version of the web driver and browser that will be used for testing. You can first update your browser and download the recommended web driver. Hope it helps sir.

Maybe you should see this video for reference to install selenium in Node environment. [Selenium With JavaScript & Node.Js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fj0Ud16YJJw&t=143s&ab_channel=CodingSrc)

Comment: Node + selenium is essentially abandoned, do you agree? Switch to Puppeteer or Playwright.

Comment: I can't answer because I'm also still learning, you can get insight by watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F22KAjATCts&ab_channel=Mukeshotwani